# Geoserver Raster layer cropped by polygon?

Tags: raster, geoserver

I've got a Geoserver raster layer which represents a satellite image. I use the Geoserver WMS to display the raster in OpenLayers. I want to display only parts of the raster - those within a certain region.

**Is it possible to send a parameter to the server (like a bbox, or a CQL expression), which will tell it to render only within a polygon?**

Can i make any 'tweaks' in OpenLayers to accomplish this behavior?
For vector layers I can use a cross-layer CQL filter in the WMS request, but what to do with a raster?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by adding a `<Transformation>` section to the SLD for your raster layer, e.g.:

```
<Transformation>
  <ogc:Function name="gs:CropCoverage">
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>cropShape</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>POLYGON ((-100 20, -60 20, -60 60, -100 60, -100 20))</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
  </ogc:Function>
</Transformation>
```

If the cropping polygon is to be specified by the user as part of the request, you can replace the `cropShape` constant above with [SLD variable substitution](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html).

Comment: I have this solution working only i have a colored bounding box outside of the clipped area. It is red, and I have some values that are red I am wondering if there is a value associated with the area within the extent outside of the clip shape that is getting assigned this color?