# Using CropCoverage Render Transformation in Geoserver SLD (WPS)?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, geotools, rendering, wps

I have yet to find an example on the web (or in code) of anyone using the "Crop Coverage" Render Transformation from a Geoserver SLD.  Does anyone have an example or at least be able to point me to the syntax of using an existing Geoserver hosted layer as a the "crop geometry?"

**[gs:CropCoverage](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/raster_processes.html)** is one of the WPS Processes used to crop raster layers.

This [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276396/18189) to [Geoserver Raster layer cropped by polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/48638/115) provides an example of using `gs:CropCoverage` with a literal crop geometry, but I need to use an existing GeoServer layer as the crop geometry.

It is also possible to chain more WPS processes in a SLD but I cannot find an example of how to use gs:CropCoverage in a SLD.

At the moment I am using Geoserver 2.4.3 on Tomcat 6.

Comment: this is basically what the op is after - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102656/how-to-crop-coverage-with-wps-chain-in-sld